# Why Is The Value Of An Uninitialized Memory Location Give The Value Of -842150451?

Tags: c++, memory, null, malloc

I was messing around with memory allocation. I was testing to see that, like Java, this program with give an exception.

```
int main() {
    int* a = nullptr;
    int b = *a;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

Which indeed it does. Then I tested using `malloc` as a pointer to `a`, but not initializing a.

```
int main() {
    int* a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int b = *a;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

However, instead of throwing an exception, it prints out a seemingly random number in -842150451. I even tried replacing int with long:

```
int main() {
    long* a = (long*) malloc(sizeof(long));
    long b = *a;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

However I got the same result. Then I tried it with short:

```
int main() {
    short* a = (short*) malloc(sizeof(short));
    short b = *a;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

Then instead of the previous result, I got -12851. And it continued like this for every primitive type I could think of. What I want to know is, where are these numbers coming from and why these numbers specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-842150451` is the two's complement representation of the value `0xCDCDCDCD`, which is a common Visual Studio debugger value for heap-allocated uninitialized memory.

Uninitialized variables or memory have *indeterminate* values from the C++ specifications perspective, and using such values lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you remember this, and always initialize such values or memory then you'll be alright.

Comment: [Magic debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Answer (score 2):

All of your erroroneous programs have what's technically called [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Which means the behaviour of the program is unconstrained by the C++ standard, and therefore it's wrong to expect any particular outcome when you run your code.

C++ is quite unlike Java in this regard which specifies precise behaviours for most situations.